# How to compress a directory with NSData Category?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compression, nsdata

I've been playing with an app and I wanted to add the ability to compress a directory and it's children.  I found the CocoaDev category often mentioned on here but eventually settled on the category put together for [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/02/molecules-source-code-now-available).  My problem is less with the compression category and more with converting a directory into a valid NSData object.  I want people to be able to deflate the file with any app out there. I have looked into NSFileManager and serializing the directory contents and compressing that, but I suspect this would prohibit the archive from being deflatable.

Where am I going wrong?  Would NSData not be sufficient?

Comment: Not sure why you want to involve nsdata

Comment: And categories, why not just tar and gzip or similar

Comment: I wanted to avoid using NSTask to run another application to do the compression.  I'm relatively new to Objective-C/Cocoa development, is it common to see applications invoking outside programs?

Comment: you should look at http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like `zip -r (more arguments here)` may work for you.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use zip via NSTask?

Comment: @Doomspork using NSTask is one way to invoke `zip`. *I wanted to avoid using NSTask to run another application to do the compression. I'm relatively new to Objective-C/Cocoa development* -- don't worry about reinventing this functionality. use something which works well, and is very compatible. you'll save a ton of time by using zip, assuming it is suitable for your needs. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  *is it common to see applications invoking outside programs?* -- well, it depends on the program, and what is being performed. judging by the question: it happens much more than you think. if you're developing software: the compiler, assembler, linker, make, your scm system and a ton of other processes are external (in most cases). external processes are very common in other apps as well.